# Can not run TestNG tests. Getting error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.usingDriverExecutable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I am implementing headless chrome browser testing using below mentioned tools:

- Ubuntu14.04LTS.
- chrome browser(58 ver. latest)
- chromedriver binary.(2.29 latest)
- Xvfb(for headless Chrome)
- jdk 1.8.0_28
- TestNG.
- required jar files selenium-java-2.53.0,selenium-chromedriver-2.26.0 and testng-6.9.9 jar files respectively.

My complete setup works perfectly fine on my local, however when I am performing whole new setup on another server, it does not works and shows for below exception during initialization of ChromeDriverService build executable. I am getting the below mentioned error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.usingDriverExecutable(Ljava/io/File;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/service/DriverService$Builder;
    at utilities.Testing.main(Testing.java:46)
```

The code line which is causing error is:

```
chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                    .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/home/ubuntu/chromedriver")).usingAnyFreePort()
                    .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY", ":1")).build();
```

I tried downgrading the chromedriver and chrome browser version on the server but still it does not works. I am compiling taking in classpath for all of the jar files and it does not shows for any compilation errors. However it only shows the error during chromeDriverService object initialization. The jdk version on my system is 1.8.0_111 which is 1.8.0_28 on server and I guess this is not a major difference of jdk versions due to which the testscripts code would not work.

Please help me in finding out solution of my problem, as I am not able to fetch out why my whole working test scripts code when shifted to another system does not works on a new system of same installations and dependencies. Also suggest me what chromedriver and chromebrowser specific versions works with each other and would not create a problem for me. Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the application cannot find the jars in the server machine. Did you add them to classpath (java -cp) and are all the paths correct?

Comment: Hi @drolmal, I have kept all jar files in 1 particular folder and I am executing

`javac -classpath .:dependencies_jars/* MyFile.java
java -classpath .:dependencies_jars/* MyFile`

All the folder paths are correct, yet not able to identify the problematic part with my setup due to which it is not executing as expected.

Comment: Tru to specify the jars by name, one by one and with the full path. That usually does the trick.

Comment: tried executing that way as well. Still it does not works for me either way. Not able to find out where the problem is. I just observed for one thing by reverse engineering for the 'selenium-java' and 'selenium-chromedriver' jar files that, the method for which the exception is thrown(ChromeDriverService$Builder.usingDriverExecutable), this method is not there in 'selenium-java' jar file while it exists in 'selenium-chromedriver' jar file only. Removing the 'selenium-java' jar file from classpath shows for compile time errors for 'WebDriver' class. Anybody can please help me in this?

Comment: Looks like could be some  kind of dependency hell, at least according to this article: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1045

Comment: seems so. More or less its a version mismatch issue of chromedriver, chrome browser and associated jar files for same. But I wonder if a same code which runs on one system, shows error on another system with all same things: the jar files, chrome browser version and chromedriver version.

Comment: Have found something regarding the issue. The chrome browser is not starting on server due to some GTK library error. This is the error comes up on opening google-chrome from terminal on server:
`ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(265)] Gtk: cannot open display:`

Working to resolve for this problem, just updated it here if anybody knows of this problem !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using Maven adding all your selenium,TestNG,WebDriver as dependencies in your POM.xml file and letting the tool download all the required jars for you instead of doing that manually

Comment: @mohammedfaisal, Will try with Maven and update on this.